# JRE for installator created in Install4j

Tags: install4j

I have application with structure:

```
/data
/docs
/j64
app.exe
etc.
```

and I need to wrap structure this into install4j installer.

There is a problem that on customer's pc is not installed java. I know that I can bundle JRE into installation package (this will be installed into target folder or into user's folder in case of shared jre). But my application already constains JRE in j64 folder, which is used for executing application. Is there any way how to use this folder for installation too? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that is not possible with install4j, you have to configure a JRE bundle.